# Method invocation pattern not working?

Tags: javascript

I am just learning about JavaScript and it has something called Methods:

An example like this I expect it to work but I wrote it in FireFox and it did nothing:

```
var myObject = {
 value: 0,
 increment: function (inc) {
   this.value += inc;
   }
};

console.writeln(myObject.value);
var x = myObject.increment(2);
console.writeln(x);
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) use `console.log` instead of `console.writeln`

2) You have to return from the function. If you don't, the only way to get the value is by requesting the value

```
var myObject = {
    value: 0,
    increment: function (inc) {
        return this.value += inc;
    }
};
```

Comment: ah! it is "log", not "writeln" ... thanks...But still shows my undefined unless I use  "return" statement. But I am reading from that book of "JavaScript, the good parts",... He is not using "return" in his example...But when I use "return" then it works.

Comment: Should the this keyword exist here? Since this is a literal object declearation.

Comment: @silentboy `this` is perfectly acceptable in this case

Comment: it is actually teaching "this", saying when a function is stored as a property of an object, it is called a method and "this" is bound to that object.

Comment: If you do not return the value, then it will never be displayed. if in this same case, you didn't return, but instead of trying to do `console.log(x)`, did `console.log(myObject.value)`, it would work. But trying to `console.log()` a function call that doesn't return anything will always return undefined

Comment: Thanks for this clearification. I am from c++ and java. Though i know javascript is java as carpet is car, i thought oop convention are same in all language. Thanks again@Jeff Shaver

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a value:

```
var myObject = {
    value: 0,
    increment: function (inc) {
        this.value += inc;
        return this.value;
    }
};
```

Also you want `console.log` not `console.writeln`

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AS9BH/

Comment: why the downvote?  I guess this has ended up as a duplicate, but I believe Jeff originally posted a different answer without the check for console.log and then deleted/reposted while I was posting this one and putting the fiddle together.  Is there anything inaccurate?

Comment: I didn't downvote.. I voted up.  I dunno who did it. Sorry Ben

Comment: @user1899082 no big deal.  Just like to know why :)